# Skip a project while building a solution using msbuild 3.5

Tags: msbuild

I have a solution with a number of libraries + web site on folder.

When I use msbuil vs. this solution it precompiles web site to a new folder name PrecompiledWeb. I want to skip it, just build all libraries.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would setup either a special target or perhaps a different msbuild file.

I use one `.msbuild` file and several different batch files, that way I can build specific parts of my application or the entire thing just by using a different batch file.

In your `.msbuild` file, you could have two targets, one for a full build and one for just the libs:

```
<Target Name="FullBuild">
  <MSBuild Projects="YourSolution.sln" />
</Target>

<Target Name="LibBuild">
  <MSBuild Projects="YourLibProject1.csproj" />
  <MSBuild Projects="YourLibProject2.csproj" />
  <MSBuild Projects="YourLibProject3.csproj" />
</Target>
```

So, you can call msbuild with either the `FullBuild` target which will build your entire solution, or with `LibBuild` which will build the specific projects you want.

Batch files might look like this:

`msbuild.exe /t:LibBuild`

`msbuild.exe /t:FullBuild`

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to do this by creating a new configuration (LibOnly) and in the Visual Studio Configuration manager only check the projects that you want to build. Then from the command line:

```
msbuild.exe YourSolution.sln /p:Configuration=LibOnly
```

As the previous commenter mentioned you can alwyas create your own MSBuild file to specify which projects to build. I think that's a good approach, I don't like building solution files.

Comment: This is nice solution, you absolutely need to add `/p:Platform=yourplatform` also, or the default "mixed platform" is used and your selections to build or not are different for each combo.